# Java Spring Boot возвращается не полная страница

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

Пишу REST приложения, в качестве бэкенда Java Spring Boot, фронтенд на голом `HTML` и `Javascript` с `Jquery`. Хочу сделать панель админа, для этого создал доступную всем страницу `/panel` на которой хотел с помощью `ajax` запросов получать другие страницы, чтобы они обновлялись без перезагрузки страницы (скорее всего это самый ужасный способ воплотить данную идею). Все казалось бы хорошо, однако при получении разметки страницы она возвращается не полностью. В оригинале где-то 2к строк, но я получаю все лишь 700-800 строк из-за чего страница отображается не коректно.

Это собственно код отправки страницы:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/panel/main")
public String getMain() {
    return "panel/trainer/index";
}
```

Есть ли какой нибудь способ передать страницу без потери данных?

Comment: не было, не было вопросов по Spring. *Гоша дударь снимает курс по Spring*. *Вопросы посыпались*

Comment: @aleksei-c может у вас css файлы не подгружаются? В том куске кода, который опубликовали ошибок нету, может в `dependency` чего-то не добавили?

Comment: @Данил, надо будет обязательно глянуть его видосы

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий, нет проблема именно в том что доходит не весь html файл, все стили есть, но некоторых частей блоков нет, может стоит какое-нибудь ограничение на объем отправляемых данных через ajax?

Comment: По вашему описанию вам никто не скажет в чем проблема. Добавьте хотя бы страницу html, укажите что приходит, что не приходит, как вы потом вставляете полученную разметку.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось довольно просто, хотя и странно, у Intellij не получалось праильно спарсить код из-за не больших ошибок в нем.

Comment: Ого! А IDEA то тут причем? Это же, грубо говоря, текстовый редактор....

Comment: @notaProgrammer IDEA, тут при том, что она не может отдать файл полностью, пока он был не правильно построен. Я же могу спокойно запустить тот же HTML в браузере и все будет работать и по сути IDEA должна была отдать его полностью, но, а тут она прошлась своим парсером и отказалась работать после тех моментов где и были ошибки